# Not able to read file from other directory even if it is open in root directory

Tags: php, xampp

I have folder structure like this:
**root** 

   **includes**

1. header.php
2. nav.php

**category**

1. content.php
2. content_form.php

I am trying to include file header.php from includes folder such as include('includes/header.php') in content.php page but I am getting error. It says directory not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try :

```
include('../includes/header.php');
```

Comment: then try `include('/includes/header.php')`

Answer (score 0):

have you added ./ front of url? include('./exapleDirectory')

Comment: and require() method?

Comment: Both are showing same error. Failed to open stream.No such file or directory in c:location